# How to dual boot using two EFI partition in same disk?

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

```
~$ lsblk -f
NAME   FSTYPE FSVER LABEL       UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                                 
├─sda1 vfat   FAT32             7A6E-FD1D                             565.3M    29% /boot/efi
├─sda2 vfat   FAT32             5E0C-C0B9                                           
├─sda3                                                                              
├─sda4 ntfs                     BC5A0E9F5A0E5694                                    
├─sda5 ntfs                     620E37E50E37B0C1                                    
├─sda6 ntfs         router_data 4416017316016770                      145.5G    48% /home/android/Documents/4416017316016770
└─sda7 ext4   1.0               45f60a44-75b5-4447-9518-f4286e68c346   76.6G    12% /
sr0
```

- `/sda1` = EFI (800 MB) used to load Linux.
- `/sda2` = EFI (100 MB) made by Windows 10.
- `/sda7` = root directory.

I used `systemd-boot` to boot my Linux.
How can I show a boot entry of Windows in the Linux boot menu?

Currently I press <kbd>F12</kbd> and select *WIndows Boot Manager* to load Windows 10.

Comment: Most systems only support one ESP per drive. You can have two FAT32 partitions and one configured as ESP, and may be able to then have second FAT32 as ESP, removing ESP flag from first and have it still work at least for a while. Updates that include boot files may then not work.

Comment: I would recommend merging the contents of the two ESPs and deleting one.

Comment: Why would one do this? The multiple OS can share a single ESP as long as it is big enough to hold all bootloaders. BTW, 800 MB seems to be pretty huge. I have a triple boot system, my ESP is 300 MB. All together I see 6 instances of grub installed in the ESP and they sum up to about 20 MB.

Answer (score 0):

Install and use **GRUB Customizer**, you can install from the Ubuntu Software Center...

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? How should GRUB be set up to achieve what the OP wants?